# Querying WMS GetFeatureInfo with known latitude and longitude

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, wms, getfeatureinfo

My issue is that normally, when you want to query a WMS layer, you need to pass width & height of a map, and x,y (in pixels) which describe a point on the map where user clicked.

I want to do this in other way - I want to query this WMS layer with longitude and latitude known before. I assume, that by using some ArcObjects libraries I will be able to convert latitude,longitude and projection to width,height,x,y so that I can use GetFeatureInfo.

How can I achieve this?

I'm using ArcObjects SDK 10.1 for .NET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simple but you must fool a bit. Feed in your lat/lon or lon/lat depending on your WMS version. Use the point as lower-left corner of BBOX and add some little number for getting the upper-right corner. Ask always for WIDTH=2 and HEIGHT=2 and pixel coordinates 1 and 1. All you need to edit ever is the BBOX. Here comes the request as exploded. I added only 0.01 degrees to BBOX for readability, it should be less to be more accurate. Perhaps 0.0001 or 0.00001 for about 10 or 1 meter resolution, respectively.

**EDIT**

The link below did work in year 2018, but I do not know who owns the  opengeo.org domain nowadays in 2024. At least they do not run GeoServer demo service. I removed the http part from the URL for breaking the link. The query parameters are still valid.

```
://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms?
bbox=-100.00,35.00,-99.99,35.01&
styles=&
format=jpeg&
request=GetFeatureInfo&
layers=topp:states&
query_layers=topp:states&
width=2&
height=2&
x=1&
y=1
```

Comment: for my wms server (mapproxy+qgis server), I had to add: `version=1.1.1&srs=epsg:4326`